# MATLAB Function block output as virtual Bus

Tags: matlab, data-structures, virtual, simulink, bus

I tried to output data from [MATLAB Function block](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) as Bus signal. As you now it can be virtual and non-virtual.

**Workaround**

I know how to create it  as nonvirtual: 
 1. Create Bus object at workspace;

```
bussignal(1) = Simulink.BusElement;
bussignal(1).Name = 'Q';
MyBus = Simulink.Bus;
MyBus.Elements = bussignal;
```

2. Define output properties of my Function Block as `Bus: myBus` at Model Explorer:[image]
3. Inside of my Function I can use now this variable `D` as structure.
And I get nonvirtual output:
[image]

**Question:**
How to make it virtual?
I want to use virtual because it doesn't create copies of data and don't create structures (avoid additional memory allocation) so can work faster for big projects.
I can make a lot of outputs and then use Bus Creator block but how to do it programmatically inside of Function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB Function supports only non-virtual buses. It converts virtual bus signal inputs to non-virtual buses. See documentation at

http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/how-structure-inputs-and-outputs-interface-with-bus-signals.html

When you need to convert input bus type to a struct for MATLAB code in the MATLAB Function block it cannot be virtual that can have noncontiguous memory.